# How to take all the values from a Treeview in tkinter and perform a while loop to go through the variables in python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, tkinter, treeview

So I have created a GUI in python that allows the user to add entries to a Treeview. I can view the results in column A, column B and column C, which are country, city and road name.

Using the following, I can get the results back for each row

```
for parent in info_tree.get_children():
    print(info_tree.item(parent)["values"])
```

This gives something like:

```
["US", "New York", "5th Street"]
["US", "LA", "Main Street"]
["UK", "London", "Waterloo Road"]
```

My question is, how can I run a while loop the rows of this dummy data that would look at the country column and while the country column remains US(or any other country), then perform an action on the city and road columns of all rows where the country is the same until a different country appears.

The solution, I believe, should be something like (pseudo code):

```
While current country == previous country:
  cty = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "city")
  cty.click()
  rd = driver.find_element(By.Name, "road")
  rd.click()
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Full Code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()

# login config
window.title("Report Generator")
window.configure(bg='blue')
window.resizable(0,0)


# main task
def run_task():
    for parent in info_tree.get_children():
        print(info_tree.item(parent)["values"])
    
frame = tkinter.Frame(bg='blue')

#treeview config
info_tree = ttk.Treeview(frame, columns=(1,2,3), show="headings", height="6")
info_tree["columns"] = ("Country", "City", "Road")

global count
count=0
data =[]
for record in data:
    info_tree.insert(parent="", index="end", iid=count,values=(record[0], record[1], record[2] ))
    count+= 1

info_tree.column("#0", width=0, stretch=NO)
info_tree.column("#1", width=120, anchor=W)
info_tree.column("#2", width=120, anchor=W)
info_tree.column("#3", width=120, anchor=W)
info_tree.heading("#0", text="")
info_tree.heading("#1", text="Country", anchor=CENTER)
info_tree.heading("#2", text="City", anchor=CENTER)
info_tree.heading("#3", text="Road", anchor=CENTER)

# insert dummy data for testing
data = [
    ["US", "New York", "5th Street"],
    ["US", "LA", "Main Street"],
    ["UK", "London", "Waterloo Road"]
]

for record in data:
    info_tree.insert("", index="end", iid=count,values=(record[0], record[1], record[2]))
    count +=1

# creating widgets
country_add = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Country:", bg='blue', fg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial 12'))
city_add = tkinter.Label(frame, text="City:", bg='blue', fg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial 12'))
road_add = tkinter.Label(frame, text="Road Name:", bg='blue', fg="#FFFFFF", font=('Arial 12'))
country_entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, font=("Arial", 10), justify=LEFT)
city_entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, font=("Arial", 10), justify=LEFT)
road_entry = tkinter.Entry(frame, font=("Arial", 10), justify=LEFT)
submit_button = tkinter.Button(frame, text="Submit", fg="#000000", font=('Arial 12'), command=run_task)


# positioning widgets
info_tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=5, padx=20, sticky=EW)
country_add.grid(row=1, column=0, pady=[10,0])
country_entry.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=[0,5], padx=[10,0], sticky=W)
city_add.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=[10,0])
city_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=[0,5], padx=[10,0], sticky=W)
road_add.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=[10,0])
road_entry.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=[0,5], padx=[10,0], sticky=W)
submit_button.grid(row=14, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=20)

frame.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Updated, hope this is sufficient

Comment: please read the page [mre]

Comment: Ok apologies. I believe I have done it correctly now

Answer (score 0):

Using a while loop is not much different than using a for loop.

For example, you could rewrite your `run_task` function like this if you wanted to only iterate the children as long as the country column has the value of "US".

```
def run_task():
    rows = info_tree.get_children()
    i = 0
    while i < len(rows) and info_tree.item(rows[i])["values"][0] == "US":
        print(info_tree.item(rows[i])["values"])
        # do something with rows that contain "US" as country
        i += 1
```

Then if you click the submit button the output is

```
['US', 'New York', '5th Street']
['US', 'LA', 'Main Street']
```